# Doubts on Green's Theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I'm trying ro understand Green's Theorem, but got stuck on some- maybe simple- problems. What exactly are C and D (see the formula below)? Knowing this, when should I use Green's Theorems? In what kind of problems it would be useful? How?
 All answers are welcome.
$$\oint_C Pdx+Qdy=\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial Q} {\partial x}-\frac{\partial P} {\partial y}\right)\,dA $$

Comment: If you google "Green's Theorem" the first result is Wikipedia. In the first line of the first result of a Google search is "In mathematics, Green's theorem gives the relationship between a line integral around a simple closed curve C and a double integral over the plane region D bounded by C"

Comment: Yes, but my question is about what D and C really mean.

Comment: It has what they mean, what precisely are you confused about? Do you know what a simple closed curve is?

Comment: Yes, I do know what it is. After thinking about it, I may have undertsood the answer.

Comment: Green's theorem is used to show the equivalence of the integral and differential forms of the Maxwell equations in the study of electromagnetism.  This may have been one of the original uses of the theorem when it was discovered.

Comment: @mathematician: I don't mean to cause conflict, but why call my answer overkill and then make this comment about differential forms?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood  huh?  Make what comment?  I was answering "In what kind of problems it would be useful".  Oh, I didn't mean differential forms like that.  I mean... the form of Maxwell's equations that uses derivatives instead of integrals.

Comment: @mathematician: At the University of Georgia, freshman and sophomores can learn differential forms in an alternative multivariable math course. Freshman also learn about Maxwell's equations in University calculus, so I don't understand how my approach was so farfetched since a freshman could be exposed to both our approaches. There is no way of knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Differential Forms Approach}$: 
Green's theorem is just a consequence of Stokes' theorem.

$$\int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_M d \omega$$

where $\omega \in \Omega^{n-1}(M)$. In our case, $D$ is our "nice set" (not necessarily a manifold), $\partial D = C$ and $\omega = P dx +  Q dy$ and so,

$$d\omega = d(P) \wedge dx + d(Q) \wedge dy = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} dy \wedge dx + \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} dx \wedge dy = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \ dx \wedge dy$$

Since $(x,y)$ are the coordinates on $ \mathbb{R}^2$ then $dA = dx \wedge dy$. In most contexts, $D$ will be an open set or a closed set in which the integrand vanishes and $\partial D$ means the boundary of $D$. To answer your question about when can you use it, well your vector field has to be $2$-dimensional or in differential forms language, $\omega$ needs to be a $1$-form.

Let me know if anything here needs to be cleared up. It is rather difficult to give a precise definition of manifold-boundary without some high-powered language, but points in the boundary for a plane region are those in which neighborhoods look like the upper half of an open disk.

$\textbf{Edit}$: Other users have made a really good point. There is no reason why I should have to use differential formats explain this. My intention was to give you a statement in terms of differential forms that helps me remember the conditions for Green's Theorem. The fact that we just need $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ means $\omega = F \cdot d \textbf{r}$ and since the exterior derivative of $1$-forms is just the curl,we have $\textrm{curl}(F) \cdot d\textbf{S} = d\omega = d(F \cdot \textbf{r})$.

$$\int_{\partial D} \omega = \oint_C F \cdot d \textbf{r} = \int_D d\omega = \int_D \textrm{curl}(F) \cdot d\textbf{S}$$

Comment: So wait, the derivative of D=C?

Comment: This is a common problem in mathematics, there are so many terms but only so few symbols. Here $\partial$ means boundary of. Yes I know in other contexts $\partial^j$ will mean derivative in direction $x^j$.

Comment: Oooh, it makes sense. Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful!

Comment: Differential forms are way overkill for someone trying to understand Green's theorem for the first time.

Comment: @mathematician: I know, I know. The OP however wanted to know what each of the ingredients meant that went into Green's Theorem. I only give this high-powered form because I wanted to show that you can get the conditions for regular Green's theorem if you have the statement in terms of differential forms.